# How to specify the TLS version ClickOnce uses

Tags: ssl, clickonce, windows-11

We are deploying a dotnet application using ClickOnce. In Windows 10 this never fails and the update and install process works as intended. But Windows 11 the installer starts and immediately reports a failure stating that the server has closed the connection. Using Wireshark the problem seems to be related to TLS.

Comparing the wireshark captures showed that the updater / installer on Windows 10 send a ClientHello message with TLS 1.2 and the same installer on Windows 11 sends this message with TLS1.0.

It is my understanding that the version sent in this message is the highest version that is supported.

I have checked internet related settings on the W11 machine and it should be able to use the latest tls version.
Is there a way to force the installer to use the latest version?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue. It turns out the issue was not related to TLS but a misconfiguration in the ClickOnce setting.
In this case the deployment url was set to use http where https should be specified. I can only assume W10 automagically corrects that, but W11 does not (and rightfully so).

The solution for this case:

- In Visual Studio open the Project properties;
- Navigate to the Publish tab;
- Press the Updates... button;
- Make sure the update location is correct.

That should solve it. It should be noted that you need to do these steps from within Visual Studio. In my experience direct edits to the UpdateUrl in the project file get reverted as soon as the project file is reloaded.